# Unable to deploy lambda function written in Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda

I am attempting to deploy my code to AWS Lambda. I've written it in Go. It builds just fine but I receive this error when running it via the Lambda test functionality:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "fork/exec /var/task/github-activity: no such file or directory",
  "errorType": "PathError"
}
```

You can view the full code at: https://github.com/JustinDFuller/github-activity
I have tested and seen that it works fine on my machine. (I've tried on windows and linux).

The file I am deploying is made by running the following commands:

`GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main awsLambdaImpl.go
zip main.zip main`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Handler for a Go Lambda is the [path to executable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-go-how-to-create-deployment-package.html).

Since you're uploading a zip file of the following structure

```
main.zip
|
`-- main  <-- executable
```

your handler name has to be `main`.

If you packed your lambda in the following way, your handler would then be

```
main.zip
|
`-- subdir
      |
      `-- executableInASubdirPackedIntoAZip  <-- executable
```

your handler would then be `subdir/executableInASubdirPackedIntoAZip`.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it! In the lambda settings I did not notice that it had a field called "handler" which was set to the name of my lambda function ("github-activity"). Changing the handler to "main" fixed the issue.